# Android Can not shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i try to save some Strings in shared preferences and then read there Strings. i wrote code witch can  write Strings in shared preferences ,but i can not read their Strings in another activity
this is a write shared preferences code

```
    SharedPreferences userDetails = this.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userDetails.edit();
    editor.putString("facebook_user_name","abc");
    editor.putString("facebook_id","hello");
    editor.commit();
```

and this is a read  shared preferences in another activity

SharedPreferences userDetails = this.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = userDetails.getString("facebook_id","");

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), language, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
```

the Toast result is null(nothink)
what am i doing wrong ? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: Are you sure `fb_id` was not null when you stored it?

Comment: yes  i changed  fb_id simple for example "me"

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely failing because you're passing in the `Activity` context in both cases rather than the `Application` context.  Since each `Activity` is unique, the `PreferenceManager` is naming the backing `SharedPreference` file differently for the 2 different contexts.  Use the `Application` context object, or use a custom name for the shared preference which both activities utilize.

Comment: That's the reason why it's recommended to always specify a dedicated name for the `SharedPreferences`. Always try to avoid using `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: Why not use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); ?

Comment: I tried to do the same by passing `this` to `getDefaultSharedPreferences` in an `Activity` and then retrieving the value in another. Why is it working?

Comment: It will work as long as the `Activity` classes are part of the same package.  If you have structured your `Activity` classes to be in different packages, then it will fail.  @XaverKapeller is right: it is usually safest to pick a name for your prefs instead of depending on the default.  Where you define that name is up to you, but I would recommend putting it in a common `static final String` instance rather than a hard coded string in the `getSharedPreferences()` call.

Comment: @Zhuinden Theoretically it's fine. But I don't like it for one reason: It's far too easy to mess up. It may work 99% of the time, but you will accidentally pass the wrong `Context` to `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` at some point and actually finding that error can be very difficult if it is not obvious (e.g. if you are in a helper method and don't really see where the `Context` is coming from). It's best to just avoid `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` all together, that little bit convenience isn't worth it.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer Its working for `Activity` in different packages too. One is in `com.a.b` and the other is in `com.c.d`

Comment: Without seeing code and it running on an actual system it's difficult to say why it would work like this.

Comment: It seems easier to make the ApplicationContext statically available and make a "helper" function that returns the default shared preferences with the static accessible app context, that way you can't possibly mess it up if there is only 1 function that provides it, with the right parameters. Or do I have this wrong?

Comment: @Zhuinden **NEVER** make a `Context` static. Or an `Activity` instance or `Service` or anything that has to do with `Context` or is a subclass of it. This will cause memory leaks, crash your app and may cause many unexplained and difficult to find bugs.

Comment: @Xaver Even the ApplicationContext? I was wondering if the Application tries to die in the background and gets restarted, or not. If it also receives onResume and onPause callbacks like an Activity (I don't know if it does!!), then it would be easy to maintain the variable without making apps crash. Activities must not be static (because the GC can't kill them at all), but I don't know about the ApplicationContext.

Comment: @Zhuinden Theoretically what you are talking about is possible. It is how a few libraries work, for example Urban Airship. But they do it differently - in a more safe way, but even than you have to be very careful, more so than you would have to in an `AsyncTask` or `Thread`. They create a custom `Application` class and implement it like a Singleton. That way you have access to the `Context` everywhere and anytime while your app is running and avoid the problem of having to save anything statically.

Comment: @XaverKapeller that's essentially what I meant - you can't really have a Singleton without private static variable and the getInstance() method for it. Now I'm curious how that "safe way" is done, I'll check into this later. I thought of extending from Application, storing itself in onCreate() (which might be bad?) in an 'instance' variable, then allowing access to the value of it via a 'getInstance()' function. Basically Singleton. There is no "onDestroy()" function in the Application... I should look into its lifecycle.

Comment: @Zhuinden Exactly. If you have a static variable somewhere in your code which does not get reset to null when it is no longer needed you are going to create a memory leak.

Comment: @Xaver I see. I didn't know that. I'll need to fix this and come up with an alternate solution then in my code. Thanks for the info :D

Answer (score 0):

Do not use:

```
.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Take this instead:

```
.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: why? you know that I mean `PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`? there should not be any syntax error

Comment: "myAppprefs is a name ,i wrote like this and i have syntacs error  SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
    .getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: why is there a space between your PreferenceManager and the "."

Comment: The problem is that there is no `PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` method.  You want `Context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`.

Comment: `SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` must work. If not, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: it would really be interesting to get a feedback